# Is there any hard evidence as to what year(s) "Superman: The Movie" (1978) occur(s)?

Tags: dc, superman-1978

Are there any definitive, objective, in-story determinations as to when "Superman" takes place, like a dateline visible on a copy of *The Daily Planet*, or a throwaway line like, 'It's 1978, Clark, ...', or just a strong suggestion?

When I say "strong suggestion," that doesn't mean the models of cars in Metropolis or the fashion, as those really reflect the production era (see "Superman Returns" which takes place just five or six years after "Superman II" which can also be considered in establishing a year), or Smallville high-school students listening to "Rock Around The Clock" or Martha and Johnathan driving x model pick-up as it should be understandable that a place like Smallville may be somewhat behind the times.

let me know if there's some "word of god" -- i.e., something noted from the Donners, or DC -- which could be taken as canonical.

BTW, on it's face, if Superman's public appearance is '78, and Clark is 30 -- having spent 12 years in the Fortress as noted by Jor-El plus leaving Smallville at 18 after graduating HS (an assumption) -- then that places his graduation in '66, and arrival on Earth in '48.

Comment: The original (not used in the film) prop newspaper "Blue Bomb Buzzes Metropolis" is copyright "1978"; https://www.thepropgallery.com/new-york-times-newspaper. The actual version appears to be identical, save for the words ***"Metropolis Times"*** pasted over the NYT logo.

Comment: The inside cover of the Daily Planet was a copy of the Daily Mail from 1978 :-) https://content.propstore.com/liveauction/lots/340supermanthemovienewspapermoney&envelope/img5.jpg?_ga=2.169331362.2082596606.1622924251-241700076.1622924251

Answer (score 15):

I believe the film was intended to be set in 1978. We can work this out using a few data points given within the original film.

Firstly, according to Jor-El (or his AI simulation, or whatever it was), Clark was 18 years old when he left Smallville and first entered the Fortress of Solitude.

> JOR-EL: My son. You do not remember me. I am Jor-El. I am your father. By now you will have reached your eighteenth year, as it is measured on Earth. By that reckoning, I will have been dead for many thousands of your years.

Secondly, according to Jor-El again, Clark spent 12 years studying under him, before arriving in Metropolis and becoming Superman. This would make Clark 30 years old at that point.

> JOR-EL: By the time we return to the confines of your galaxy, twelve of your years will have passed.

Finally, according to Luthor, Superman stated in his interview with Lois that Krypton exploded in 1948, and that he arrived on Earth three years later.

> LUTHOR: In the interview he says that the planet Krypton exploded in 1948. Ridiculous little freak took three years in a rocket ship to get to Earth.

Clark (or Kal-El, as he was named at the time) was a newborn infant when Krypton exploded, so if he was 30 years old when he became Superman, that would mean the majority of the film was set in 1978.

Jor-El did appear to contradict himself though, when he stated that he would've been dead for many thousands of years by the time Kal-El/Clark reached his eighteenth year. We know Clark was born shortly *before* Jor-El died, so that's a contradiction right there. And Clark told Lois that Krypton exploded in 1948, and that the journey from Krypton to Earth took three years, so that's another contradiction.

We could speculate that Krypton did explode many millennia ago, and that baby Kal-El's aging was drastically slowed during his journey to Earth, as a result of his rocket ship travelling at near-lightspeed. But that wouldn't explain how Jor-El knew about Einstein and early Chinese writings.

> JOR-EL: ...which Einstein called his Theory of Relativity. Embedded in the crystals before you, is the total accumulation of all literature and scientific fact from dozens of other worlds, spanning the 28 known galaxies...

> JOR-EL: Early Chinese writings point out the complex relationship between...

Jor-El mentioned that baby Kal passed through six galaxies on his way to Earth, which suggests that he travelled a vast distance which would've taken at least *tens of thousands of years* to cover at near-lightspeed (assuming that galaxies are similarly as far apart in that universe as they are in the real world).

> JOR-EL: Each of the six galaxies which you will pass through contain their own individual law...

If Jor-El died at least tens of thousands of years ago, he shouldn't have known anything about Einstein or early Chinese writings, unless he had the ability to see the future. And it seems unlikely that Kryptonians had that ability, since most of them clearly didn't foresee the destruction of their own planet.

Another (arguable) contradiction to the aforementioned timeline occurs in *Superman III*, when the banners/signs at Clark's high school reunion indicate that the reunion was being held for the Class of 1965. However, it is possible that Clark graduated at 17 years of age, rather than 18.

[image]

Comment: @Stak-Ex - If you're satisfied with this answer, please mark it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Thanks.

Comment: Great answer.  I think that at least one of the contradictions has an explanation. Kal's ship was traveling at near light speed, thus experienced time dilation. It took thousands of years to arrive, but Kal experienced just 3 years ship time.

Comment: @Pete - That possibly occurred to me, and I was going to mention it in my answer. The reason I didn't is that it doesn't fit with Superman telling Lois that Krypton exploded in 1948. We could assume that Superman was wrong about the year of Krypton's demise, but Krypton exploding thousands of years ago doesn't fit with Jor-El being familiar with Albert Einstein and his Theory of Relativity.

Comment: I didn't say it explained ALL  the contradictions, just one of them.  Did the dialogue specifically mention Einstein? The same theory would have been discovered by Kryptonian scientists.

Comment: @Pete - It solves one contradiction, but creates two more, which isn't very helpful. And yes, Jor-El did specifically mention Einstein by name. You can see the dialogue quoted in the lower half of my answer, and I posted a video clip of the scene in question just below the quote. I guess I should probably rephrase my answer to emphasise that Jor-El indicated a familiarity with Einstein specifically, rather than just the concept of the Theory of Relativity.

Comment: The mention of Einstein's theory of relativity might just be a bad translation from Kryptonian to English - a bad or just toned down to be understood by audience.

Comment: @Pere - Jor-El also mentioned "early Chinese writings"; the word "China" has only been used on Earth since the 16th century. And if we're questioning the accuracy of what Jor-El said anyway, due to possible translation errors or whatnot, the most obvious target is his statement that he died thousands of years ago. That's the outlier in terms of the various data points the Salkind movies give us. Everything else conforms to a trend suggesting that Krypton exploded decades, rather than millenia, ago.

Comment: As another example, in _Supergirl_ (1984), Kara is clearly stated to be Kal-El's teenage cousin, and she's still alive in the 1980s. Not only that, but she's aware that Kal-El is now known as both Superman and Clark Kent, and that he works at the Daily Planet newspaper.

Comment: @Stak-Ex - I see you've been attempting to respond to my answer via edits rather than comments, and you've explained that you can no longer access your original account, since your cookies crumbled. If you wish, you can solve this problem by registering a new account, and then following the instructions provided at [this link](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge the new account with your original one. That would enable you to accept the answer and post comments within this thread, and an acceptance would be appreciated.

Comment: You can also mention that, in the desert, as she stops to get gas or ask directions, Lois Lane lowers the window in her car and you hear the car radio playing a song by Supertramp (Give a Little Bit) - the song came out in 1977.  So it is placed in or after 1977. (This is a set up for when the dam breaks during the earthquake scene). I remember laughing at this when I first saw the movie: Superman/Supertramp juxtaposition.(Yeah, I saw it when it came out)

Comment: @Stak-Ex - You don't need to make a habit of using Google to join this site. You just need to open a Gmail account, or a Facebook account. It's worth the effort, as this is a good site, and you can't interact with it properly without an account here.